# Script for File system monitoring aix

Tags: shell, unix, awk, filesystems

i'm trying to create a script which will show filesystem which are utilized over 69% and exclude file system with name bkp or archival also if all file system is under 69% then script should just print single 'ok' message

using below script i'm able to achieve 1st part of my requirement but where i require just single 'ok' script output shows ok for multiple times (same as no of file system present on machine) can someone help me to get just single ok if every filesystem  is below threshold value ?

```
echo `df -k |awk '{print $7, $4}'|cut -d '%' -f1| awk '{if ($2>69)print $1, $2 ;else print "ok"}'|grep -vE "bkp|archival"`
```

normal output (i don't want to see 'ok' here but only file system names where threshold is crossed )

```
\ok ok ok /var 74 /tmp 79 ok ok /opt 74 ok /db2/tdb_instlocal 83 ok /LOGS 78 ok ok /db2/t1reorg 75 ok ok ok /bkg_26AS 79 ok ok ok /templogship 73 ok /dumptest 79 ok ok /db/n1db10 82 /db/n1db11 82 /db/n1db12 81 /db/n1db13 83 /db/n1db14 82 /db/n1db15 82 /db/n1db16 87 /db/n1db17 81 /db/n1db18 81 /db/n1db9 83 /db2/t1log 77 ok ok ok ok ok /db2/tdb_inst_l3 87 ok ok ok ok /db2/tdb_inst3 87 ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok
```

if everything is under threshold value(below 69 %) then it should only shown single 'ok'

hope some will help me to fix my scipt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(It seems like the output of my `df -k` is different than yours.. I have the amount of use as $5, whereas you have it as $4. Further, the name of the file system is $1, whereas you use $7) On my machine, the following seems to work

```
df -k | awk -f print.awk
```

where `print.awk` is

```
NR> 1{
    sub(/%/,"",$5)
    if ($5 > 69) {
       if (!match($1,/bkp|archival/)) {
         print $5, $1; f=1
       }
    }
}

END { if (!f) print "ok" }
```

or as a one liner:

```
df -k | awk 'NR> 1{ sub(/%/,"",$5);  if ($5 > 69) { if (!match($1,/bkp|archival/)) { print $5, $1; f=1; } } } END { if (!f) print "ok" }'
```

Comment: Good one! Also, to get rid of the `%` in the 5th column you can also do `$5=$5*1` or `$5=$5+0`

Comment: thx hakon is it possible to make it one liner script i want to deploy it for monitoring and trying to avoid creating local script on multiple machines, that's why my script is one liner..:)